# Is あんな面して some kind of idiomatic expession?

Tags: nuances, reading-comprehension

Upon asking "What do you think of that guy?" two characters reply this:

> 彼優しいよね

And the other character replies

> あんなツラしてお節介なのよ

I understand the second reply is akin to "He's a meddler" but what kind of nuance is あんなツラして trying to say? Obviously the character is not presented in the scene, so I suppose he's saying... he has a certain type of face?

She is, from a broader context, using お節介 affectionately I believe, so I don't think he's saying he's ugly.

Answer (score 3):

あんな面して means あんな面しているのに/していても though it is almost never written in full (i.e., used as あんな面して). The meaning is quite literal '(even) though [subject] has such a face'='despite the appearance' as mentioned in @Gui Imamura's answer.

It basically implies the person does not look like having the property being mentioned.

Comment: So when we see 面 how do we know which reading to use?  I've always just read it as メン whenever it seemed that the meaning was to mean *face* or *mask*.  つら just never occurs to me.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @A.Ellett "Improve your vocabullary"... is all I can think of, unfortunately. [つら is a common on-yomi](https://kanji.jitenon.jp/kanji/416.html) for this kanji. When this kanji is used as "めん" it usually means "aspect/side", "plane/surface", "mask/face guard"; and it is rarely used with the meaning of "face" except when a match of 剣道 (kendō) is involved or when using an idiomatic expression like 面が割れる.

Comment: @GuiImamura Unfortunately, you're probably right.  But also, my exposure to Japanese is primarily through reading.  So, while I think my vocabulary is decent, I don't necessarily always know which reading to use for a particular kanji, particularly when there are no additional clues such as okurigana or a compound--such as in this example.  Most of my Japanese I picked up before the era of the internet.  I think familiarity through hearing helps a great deal.  So, I try greatly to listen to more and more topics.  It's an interesting challenge.

Comment: @A.Ellett As a rough approximation (already mentioned by @GuiImamura), つら is face (vulgar register) and めん is a side/surface of an object. めんが割れる is an idiomatic expression, but つらが割れている sounds ok to me.

Answer (score 1):

> despite that face

No, I don't think that's an idiomatic expression.